# Why does Python say that I can't convert a string into an integer because it has empty strings?

Tags: python, integer

I'm making a procedure that takes in two coordinates as input, then calculating the midpoint. However, when I try to change the input into an integer after just taking the part of the coordinate with the x and y values, it says ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' <--That's an empty string by the way. Here's my code:

```
def distance():
    p1=input('Input your first point:')
    p2=input('Input your second point:')
    split1=p1.find(',')
    x1=int(p1[2:split1-1])
    y1=p1[split1+1:-2]
    split2=p2.find(',')
    x2=p2[0:split2-1]
    y2=p2[split2+1:-1]
    x=x2-x1**2
    y=y2-y1**2
    d=(x+y)**.5
    print('This is the distance between those points',d)`
```

Comment: What number would you expect an empty string to be converted to?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you call int('') and therefor you get an error?

Comment: I don't expect an empty string to be converted into a number, I'm splitting a coordinate to get a number, then converting that to an integer. Python just says that I can't because there's an empty string in it.

Comment: Didn't you forget braces in `x=x2-x1**2`?

Comment: Maybe the decimal separator. It can be "." or ",". If you use the other one for split and there is not a character like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, `int('')` will yield this error because there is not a general consensus on what number `''` should be converted to.

If you actually want a default value, consider using the following (where you want it to default to 0).

```
value = ''
intvalue = int(value or '0')

# 0

value = '1'
intvalue = int(value or '0')

# 1
```

That being said, an easier way to accomplish splitting the coordinates like you want would be to use `split()`

```
x,y = map(int, '1,2'.split(','))
```

If your input is actually of the form: `(1, 2)`, you will want to ignore the parentheses and only grab the numeric parts.

```
import re

val = '(1, 2)'
val = re.sub('\(|\)', '', val);
x,y = map(int, val.split(','))
```

Or more generically

```
val = '(-1, 2)' # or [-1, 2] or -1,2

val = re.search('\-?\d+\s*,\s*\-?\d+', val).group()
x,y = map(int, val.split(','))
```

For your specific example:

```
def getxy(val):
    val = re.search('\-?\d+\s*,\s*\-?\d+', val)

    # Alert the user if invalid input was provided
    if val is None:
        raise Exception('Invalid input')

    # Convert all coordinates to integers
    return map(int, val.group().split(','))

x1, y1 = getxy(input('Input your first point:'))
x2, y2 = getxy(input('Input your second point:'))
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your split suggestion with a replace function, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use something like [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) instead of fancing indexing to parse your input:

```
def distance():
    p1=input('Input your first point:')
    p2=input('Input your second point:')
    x1, y1 = p1.split(',', 1)
    x1 = int(x1)
    y1 = int(y1)
    x2, y2 = p2.split(',', 1)
    x2 = int(x2)
    y2 = int(y2)
    x=x2-x1**2
    y=y2-y1**2
    d=(x+y)**.5
    print('This is the distance between those points',d)`
```

Comment: Python returned ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(1' to me, hence my need to remove the first parenthesis, and yes, I have tried replace.

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the first two characters of your point, so if the number has only two digits, you get an empty string. Better split the string with `split`:

```
p1 = '(1,4)'
x1, y1 = p1[1:-1].split(',')
x1 = int(x1)
```

Comment: In my code, I meant [1:split-1], not 2. I tried it with 1 before and it didn't work, so I was experiementing

Comment: with `[1:split-1]` you miss the first and last character of the first number. Correct would be `[1:split]`, if your point-definition contains parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I'm still not entirely sure what I did wrong, but I added a comma split clause. In the beginning, I used replace like I did here, but it didn't work. This time, it did! Thanks to everyone who tried to help. Here's my solution:

```
def distance():
p1=input('Input your first point:')
p2=input('Input your second point:')
rp1=p1.replace('(','').replace(')','')
x1, y1 = rp1.split(',', 1)
x1 = int(x1)
y1 = int(y1)
rp2=p2.replace('(','').replace(')','')
x2, y2 = rp2.split(',', 1)
x2 = int(x2)
y2 = int(y2)
x=(x2-x1)**2
y=(y2-y1)**2
d=(x+y)**.5
print('This is the distance between those points',d)
```

Comment: I would definitely recommend looking through some of the tips in the other answers for ideas on how to improve this and make it more robust.

Comment: Definitely, but this is just an assignment I had to finish for my computer science class. I just wanted to work out some kinks so I could get over it. Seeing as I'm in middle school and have no interest working in any sort of engineering field, I don't mind having an inefficient or incompetent piece of code.

Comment: Kudos to you for learning this stuff at an early age! I'm not saying that this is a bad solution by any means, it's just that we all learn by looking at the tips and tricks of others! I hope you learn a lot from your course though as programming is extremely beneficial for any field, even those outside of engineering.

Comment: This is the first time I've logged on in three years, and I just want to say that I appreciate it! Also, I'm entering physics and currently doing an astrophysics internship that is primarily coding, so three years later, I eat my words. Just thought you should know :^)

Comment: congratulations! :)